# How to disable upper/lowercase as unimportant discrepancy in beyond compare

Tags: beyondcompare, beyondcompare3

Currently I am ignoring unimportant discrepancies in beyond compare. I just realized that the upper and lower case belongs as unimportant discrepancies. Is there any way we can treat this as important discrepancy?

Answer (score 0):

Start your compare, select the menu option *File..Session Settings...*.

In the dialog that pops up, click the *Importance* tab and make sure the check box labelled *Character Case* is checked.